# Python will not open shell

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell

I  think it is called a shell. the window that one writes and runs python in.
I have installed python 2.7.135;   it runs from command line, but will not open when clicking on the python gear icon in dolphin.

```
michaeleric@michaeleric-Inspiron-1750:~/Desktop/Python-2.7.13$ ls  
aclocal.m4     config.log      configure      Doc             install-sh   
LICENSE        Makefile.pre    Modules        PC              pyconfig.h
Python         RISCOS          build          config.status   configure.ac    
Grammar        Lib             Mac            Makefile.pre.in Objects        
PCbuild        pyconfig.h.in   python-gdb.py  setup.py        config.guess  
config.sub     Demo            Include        libpython2.7.a  Makefile     
Misc           Parser         pybuilddir.txt  python          README 
Tools
```

Am I  missing something?

when I  installed in on win7, it opened a shell that i could program, save,  and run.  In kubuntu 14.xx I can only open it  in command line.

Comment: You seem to have a bash UNIX (like) OS. On most of them Python is already installed. Just run `python` at the prompt. Also there seems to be a `python` file in that folder. Try to run `./python` there.

Comment: A lot answer on stack, Did you declared any MIME types ? Did you have any permission `a+x` on related file ?

Comment: @dsgdfg, no MINE declared, no clue what that is. no clue what is meant by permission a+x

Comment: @KlausD., "it runs from command line, but will not open when clicking on the python gear icon in dolphin"

Comment: Off course your OS very smart cos know your choice `edit/run/file_opt`. Create a `my_exec.desktop` file and determine what you want !  Your point is not right....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should add more context and clarity to the question.
From what I understand, Python, in Windows environment, comes bundled with the IDLE - a window to write programs and run and another one to see the execution results. https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html

You may install a Python IDE (PyCharm, Sublime), etc. or just use the bare-bone python shell. If the linux machine is local, then you may also run IDLE itself.

Comment: thank you. you answered the question.  i am missing the ide, which is bundled in winblows and expected it to also be bundled for linux.

Answer (score 0):

you have to run it via comandline.
run cmd dir to directory and than type in python type in not clicking